# Getting run time error when trying to connect to oracle-sql developer using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using below connection string to connect to oracle-sql developer using VBA. Getting an error message as attached in the screen print. Does anyone has idea bout the root cause of issue and the resolution for same.

[image]

connection string:

```
strConnection = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
"CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
"(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
"(HOST=host_name)(PORT=1111))" & _
"(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=serv_nm))); uid=qauser; pwd=123;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing Oracle Client solved the issue